# $\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 \frac1{\tan^px}\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $p\ge 0$

Tags: calculus

Use substitution $u=\frac\pi2 -x$ to prove the above integral always equals $\frac\pi4$ for all values of $p$

When I did the substitution I got
$$
\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\tan^px}{1 + \tan^px}\mathrm{d}x
$$ between the same limits as original integral.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: I seriously doubt thing converges: the point $\;x=0\;$ makes things pretty ugly to the cotangent function (for $\;p=1\;$ it undoutedly diverges)

Comment: With the substitution you get $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^p x\,dx$.

Comment: it converges only if $|p|<1$.

Comment: @Timbuc: my apologies, the SE app doesn't work very well for Math.SE so far...

Answer (score 2):

For $\;p=1\;$ get:

$$\int_0^{\pi2}\frac{dx}{\tan x}=\int_0^{\pi2}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}dx=\left.\log\sin x\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\log\sin\frac\pi2-\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\log\sin\epsilon=0+\infty$$

Thus, the integral does not converge for **all** values $\;p\ge 0\;$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $p\in(0,1)$, let $u=\sin x$ and then
$$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\tan^px}dx=\int_0^1u^{-p}(1-u^2)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}du$$
Now use the Beta function to get the integral (see the detail in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). You can check that the answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\frac{p\pi}{2}$.

Comment: This works for $p\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: @Mehdi, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}}
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}
+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}
+\int_{-\pi/4}^{0}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x + \pi/2}}
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}
-\int_{\pi/4}^{0}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{-x + \pi/2}}
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\bracks{%
{1 \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}} + {1 \over \cot^{p}\pars{x}}}\,\dd x
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\pars{1}
\end{align}

> $$
> \color{#66f}{\large%
> \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}}
> =\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\bracks{%
> \cot^{p}\pars{x} + \tan^{p}\pars{x}}\,\dd x
> $$
>   The first integral
>   $\ds{\pars{~\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cot^{p}\pars{x}\,\dd x~}}$ converges whenever
>   $\ds{\Re\pars{p} < 1}$ while the second one
>   $\ds{\pars{~\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\tan^{p}\pars{x}\,\dd x~}}$ converges whenever
>   $\ds{\Re\pars{p} > -1}$

$$
\mbox{Then,}\quad\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over \tan^{p}\pars{x}}}\quad\mbox{converges whenever}\quad
\verts{\Re\pars{p}} < 1
$$

> Expression $\pars{1}$ can be evaluated with the change
>   $\ds{\quad\sin\pars{x} \equiv t\quad}$ via the *Beta function* as
>   ${\tt @xpaul}$ pointed out.